# $(SolutionDir) in MS VisualStudio Build events

Tags: visual-studio, xcopy, post-build-event

```
XCOPY /Y /E "$(SolutionDir)CopyOnBuild\*.*" ".\"
```

is the command right now. Which tell that the directory to copy files is at same level where the sln is. 
My Question is: I want to copy the files to a directory which is one level above the solution directory. How the command should be?

Comment: ".." (two dots) refers to the parent directory.  So consider "$(SolutionDir).."

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to change the destination dir, and make it one level up, try putting two dots instead of one:

```
XCOPY /Y /E "$(SolutionDir)CopyOnBuild\*.*" "..\"
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I was able to do it with 
     XCOPY /Y /E "$(SolutionDir)..\CopyOnBuild\*.*" ".\"